# How to check for return statuses of piped commands in ash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to check for the return codes for processes piped to each other in ash shell?

Here is the command I am interested in:

```
dd if=/my/block/device | ssh myuser@otherserver "gzip > file.gz"
```

Also, I know this has been answered for bash shell (i.e., using PIPESTATUS array), but I am my environment uses ash shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `ash` at all. This *general workaround* should work even in `sh`:

```
psf=/tmp/pipestatus
: > "$psf"   # to make the file empty
( dd if=/my/block/device; echo "1 $?" >> "$psf" ) \
| ( ssh myuser@otherserver "gzip > file.gz"; echo "2 $?" >> "$psf" )
```

Then you check the content of `/tmp/pipestatus`. There is a flaw: race condition, the two `( )` blocks run in parallel, they may output to the file not in the right order. I used `>>` so neither message will overwrite the other; the "messages" are short, so they shouldn't get interleaved; i numbered the "messages", so even if they are not in order, you can retrieve the right order later (`sort`, `cut`).

The above code is just an example anyway. More robust solution uses `mktemp` to create a temporary file(s), `printf` instead of `echo`. To get rid of race condition entirely, you need to write to *separate* files:

```
psd="$(mktemp -d)"
# you may want to check if the above command succeeded

( dd if=/my/block/device; printf '%s\n' "$?" > "$psd/f1" ) \
| ( ssh myuser@otherserver "gzip > file.gz"; printf '%s\n' "$?" > "$psd/f2" )

# retrieve the results here, they are in "$psd/f1" and "$psd/f2"

rm -rf "$psd"
unset psd
```

It's not as good as Bash's `PIPESTATUS` because it relies on some filesystem and ability to write there, few things can go wrong and may not be caught. Still better than nothing.

Comment: Note: I will upvote any answer better than mine; in particular an answer that uses `ash`-specific *right* way (if any) to solve the issue. If you write such an answer then leave me a comment under my answer.